# Prove that for any $W\in Q$, there exist a bijection $f:[0]\to W$

Tags: analysis, functions, relations

Suppose $R$ be the relation on $[0,1)$ s.t. $aRb\iff a-b$ is rational. Let $[0]$ be the equivalence class with respect to relation $R$ on $[0,1)$. Let $Q$ be the set of all equivalence class on [0,1). Prove that for any $W\in Q$, there exist a bijection $f:[0]\to W$, where $f(z)=z+g$ if $z+g<1$ and $f(z)=z+g-1$ when $z+g\ge1, g\in [0,1)$ and $z\in [0]$.

Attempts: I know that $[0]$ is indeed the set of all rational number in $[0,1)$. So when $W=Q$, it is trivial by definining the function letting $f(z)=z,g=0$. When $A\ne Q$, then $A$ is set of irrational numbers $\in [0,1)$ but then i am not so sure how to prove it since there are uncountably many irrational numbers

Comment: Shouldn't this say that $W \in Q$ rather than $W \subset Q$?  Isn't $W$ an equivalence class and $Q$ is the set of all equivalence classes?

Comment: First of all, there's indeed a notational problem that makes it harder to understand your problem. I will assume that you're trying to prove that there exists a bijection between any equivalence class and the equivalence class of 0.

You're right in saying that there are only countably many elements in $[0]$, while $[0,1)$ is uncountable. If you have a countable number of equivalence classes, this would cause trouble (a countable union of countable sets is countable). But what prevents you from having uncountably many equivalence classes?

Comment: Write $W$ as $[w]$. Define $f(z) = z + w$ if $z+w < 1$, $f(z) = z + w - 1$ otherwise. Prove that $f$ is well defined (i.e the image of $f$ is included in $W$). Then prove it is injective (quite obvious I think) and it is surjective (hint: for any $w_1 \in W, w_1 = w + q$ where $q$ is rational...)